# SQL order by created and due date expired

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, jpql

I am working on a project where we have a collection of requests. I need to show the requests by their date of creation. However, I also need to show first those which have their due date expired. Here is the POJO class:

```
 @Entity
 @XmlRootElement
 @NamedQueries({
     @NamedQuery(name="Question.findAll", query="SELECT a FROM Request a ORDER BY a.created DESC"),
 })
 public class Request {

    Date created;
    Date duedate;
    String name;

    public Request () {}

    public static boolean isOverdue(){
         if duedate.before(new Date())) return true; else return false;
    }

    // omitting getter setters
 }
```

How can I write the JPQL statement in order to get the list of Requests ordered by date of creation but show first those which have their due date expired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t know JPQL but I assume you can execute ordinary sql such as:

`SELECT a FROM Request a 
 ORDER BY coalesce(a.duedate, a.created) DESC`

or

`SELECT a FROM Request a 
 ORDER BY coalesce(case when a.duedate < now() then duedate end, a.created) DESC`